# How to reference an image inside another tag with 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is pretty basic, I'm trying to get the 'src' attribute of some images and put them in the same number of #image fields:

```
        count = 0;
        $('.selected').each(function() {
            count++;
            // the idea is to get the value from each ".selected img"
            $('#image' + count).val(   this + img   ).attr("src");
        });
```

How to reference the image from 'this' ? or what would be the good method ? .... Thanks !

**EDIT:**

I have something like this:

```
        <li><img src="..." alt="" class="selected" /></li>
        <li><img src="..." alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="..." alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="..." alt="" class="selected" /></li>
```

I want to write the src attribute of those img s in this:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="image1" name="image1" value="" />                  
    <input type="hidden" id="image2" name="image2" value="" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this the sort of thing you mean?**

```
$(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $('.selected').each(function() {
        count++;
        var source = $('img', this).attr('src');
        $('input#image' + count).val(source);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img.selected').each(function(i, img) {
    $('#image' + (i + 1)).val(img.src);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you'd like to put the `src` attribute in each associated `hidden` field tag, is that correct? I'm a little confused as to the distinction between the use of selected vs non-selected images, so I'm ignoring that in this solution:

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="src0" alt="" class="selected" /></li>
    <li><img src="src1" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="src2" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="src3" alt="" class="selected" /></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="image0" name="image0" value="" />                  
<input type="text" id="image1" name="image1" value="" />  
<input type="text" id="image2" name="image2" value="" />  
<input type="text" id="image3" name="image3" value="" />
```

**Script**:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(idx, e){
    $(this).val($($('img')[idx]).attr('src'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/MDfD9/

(I used text fields here for illustration, but you could change the attributes to hidden easily)

Of course, this assumes that each image has an associated input field. I'm a little curious as to *why* you're going down this path though.. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? From what I've seen, there may be other ways of going about it..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean.

```
    $('.selected').each(function(idx, obj) {
        $('#image' + (idx + 1)).attr("src", obj.src);
    });
```